# Add scene to asset browser collection

Tags: asset-browser

How do you add an entire scene as an asset in the asset browser?

I.e. in my blend file I have Scene 1 and Scene 2, and I'd like to have Scene 2 be an asset available to me in other blend files via the Asset Browser.

Comment: In Version 3.0 you can only add Materials, Objects, Actions and Worlds, not Scenes.

Comment: @Gorgious poses, not actions?

Comment: Hmm you may very well be right, sorry ! :)

Comment: After (at least) 3.3 collections can be marked as assets. You should be able to put the whole scene into a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, as of blender 3.0 scenes are not supported in the asset browser.

Answer (score 1):

After (at least) 3.3 collections can be marked as assets. You should be able to put the whole scene into a collection.